# Calculation mistake in Conway's complex analysis book

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387903283) and I think Conway made a mistake in a calculation. He want to prove that if a function satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations, then $f$ is analytic. The first step is defining things and using the mean value theorem

[image]

Afterwards, he defines $\varphi$ and $\psi$ and concludes $\frac{f(z+s+it)-f(z)}{s+it}=u_x(z)+iv_x(z)+\frac{\varphi(s,t)+\psi(x,t)}{s+it}$, see:

[image]

Following my calculations we have to have $\frac{f(z+s+it)-f(z)}{s+it}=u_x(z)+iv_x(z)+\frac{\varphi(s,t)+i\psi(x,t)}{s+it}$.

Did Conway make a mistake?

Comment: What a mess. It's simpler to just assume that if $u,v$ are real differentiable at a point, with $u,v$ satisfying CR there, then $u+iv$ is complex differentiable at the point.

Comment: @zhw. That's exactly he wants to prove

Comment: It's probably just a typo.

Comment: No, he's using a stronger assumption, namely $u,v$ are $C^1$ in the domain, to prove a result for the whole domain, using the MVT unnecessarily, that is really better cast as a pointwise result. Anyway, yes, you need $i\psi$ there at the end.